# @OneToMany or @ManyToMany mapping error during insertion in Database

Tags: hibernate, object, mapping, relation

```
public String createExam(HttpServletRequest request, Model model) throws Exception {
    QuestionBankService questionbankService = (QuestionBankService) context.getBean("fetchQuestion");
    HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);
            SessionFactory sessionfactory = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
    Session sessions = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    String examId = request.getParameter("examid");
    String examName = request.getParameter("examname");
    String examDate = request.getParameter("examdate");
    String examDuration = request.getParameter("examduration");
```

Now I am getting the following error when I am trying to run this code at line SessionFactory sessionfactory = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();.

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Use of @OneToMany or @ManyToMany targeting an unmapped class: org.iitb.exam.main.dto.Exam.questionBank[org.iitb.exam.main.dto.QuestionBank]
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:948)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:838)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:812)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
```

- root cause

  org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Use of @OneToMany or @ManyToMany targeting an   unmapped class: org.iitb.exam.main.dto.Exam.questionBank[org.iitb.exam.main.dto.QuestionBank]
  org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.CollectionBinder.bindManyToManySecondPass(CollectionBinder.java:1185)
  org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.CollectionBinder.bindStarToManySecondPass(CollectionBinder.java:710)
  org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.CollectionBinder$1.secondPass(CollectionBinder.java:645)
  org.hibernate.cfg.CollectionSecondPass.doSecondPass(CollectionSecondPass.java:65)
  org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.originalSecondPassCompile(Configuration.java:1716)
  org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.secondPassCompile(Configuration.java:1423)
  org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1856)
  org.iitb.exam.main.formcontrollers.ExamCreatedFormController.createExam(ExamCreatedFormController.java:60)
  sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
  sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
  sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
  java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
  org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:219)
  org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
  org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
  org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:745)
  org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:686)
  org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80)
  org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:925)
  org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856)
  org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:936)
  org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:838)
  javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
  org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:812)
  javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)

I am not able to understand where i am doing wrong. I came to know that something is wrong with Exam.java related to QuestionBand for which the code written is as follows

```
    @ManyToMany(cascade = { CascadeType.ALL })
    @JoinTable(name = "QuestionBank_Exam_Mapping",
             joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "examid")},
             inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "questionid") })
private Set<QuestionBank> questionBank = new HashSet<QuestionBank>();
```

I want to create just exam entry by giving an userinteface to the user where he will enter some required parameters like exam name, exam date, exam duration etc.
There is a another dependency where again i have to make an entry for the exam created by using the examid in advt_exam_post table mappin. I have advtid and postid in session, so i can make an entry in that table. My confusion is why it is showing me error for the questionbank. In questionbank and exam table mapping there is dependency with the examid and questionid, which will be filled only when the user selects a particular question for a particular exam.

Now please let me know where i am actually doing some wrong stuff and creating a mess in my code. Wasted a load amount of time in debuggin this :(

Answer (score 0):

The error states that `QuestionBank` is not an entity. If it is not an entity, you should either make it one or map to a different type.

```
Use of @OneToMany or @ManyToMany targeting an unmapped class: org.iitb.exam.main.dto.Exam.questionBank
```

The package name 'dto' suggests that the type is not intended to be an entity. Perhaps you are expecting another type there, like `org.iitb.exam.main.domain.exam.QuestionBank`, so you should also check your imports fi your DTOs and entities have identical type names. Having identical type names in this case is discouraged for the reason of confusion potential.

Comment: but QuestionBank is an entity
    package org.iitb.exam.main.dto;

@Entity
@Table(name = "QuestionBank")
public class QuestionBank implements Serializable{

Comment: as you didnt post the relevant code I was guessing, extrapolating from the exception message. If you post the QuestionBank code, I'll adapt the answer accordingly.

Comment: @user3253087 are you sure you have only  single definition of QuestionBank? Since the 'dto' package would be an unusual place to put it in. DTOs and entities are two different concepts.

Comment: I might be wrong in naming the package.  And yes I have only single definition of QuestionBank.. Inorder to avoid confusion again i have written a code for fetching Question sets and used it in the Controller for creating exam but still no use.

Comment: I am confused why it is giving error while building the session itself i.e on this line SessionFactory sessionfactory = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();

Comment: To reiterate: the reason for the error is most probably in the definition of the QuestionBank. Please do post the complete code for this class, including the annotations. Without this information I do not know how to help you further.

Comment: I was to able to rectify that error. The problem occurred as there was no mapping for the QuestionBank in the hibernate.cfg.xml file. Now the problem is I am getting the session as null. The code for the file is as follows:
    public String createExam(HttpServletRequest request, Model model) throws Exception {
  HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);
  SessionFactory sessionfactory = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
  Session sessions = sessionFactory.openSession //I am getting error on this line

Comment: Glad you could fix the problem :) The Session retrieval is a different issue, so feel free to open a new question.